# what would "<_ZThn24_N15[Some namespace]22[Some class name]D1Ev>" mean in gdb?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, coredump

I'm trying to debug one core dump and I've found structure, whose first variable points to `0x00000055558..`
when I type `x 0x00000055558..`, it outputs:

```
0x55558.. <_ZTVN15NameSpace22ClassNameE+16>:    0x0000005..
```

Does that means there is a variable of this class defined here? Trying to go 16 bytes back and casting this to ClassName does not give valid values.

Sorry for such newbie question, but I couldn't find that in google for quite a lot of time.

Comment: Google for name mangling, and then take the real name (not the one you wrongly made up for this question) and pass it to c++filt

Comment: Thank you! I don't know c++filt before you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing a [mangled name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). You can tell GDB to demangle it for you (or better yet, demangle names from now on):

```
set print demangle on
```

According to [this website](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_58.html), this command tells GDB to:

> Print C++ names in their source form rather than in the encoded ("mangled") form passed to the assembler and linker for type-safe linkage. The default is on.

Also, to see the code at a certain address, you can write:

```
l *0x<address>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the other answers for ways to demangle that symbol name.  It will probably turn out to be something like "vtable for NameSpace::ClassName".  (g++ symbols beginning with _ZTV are vtables.)

Finding a pointer to an offset inside a vtable is usually a very good indication that you have found memory containing an object whose most-derived type is that class.  It doesn't guarantee it's not left over deallocated memory or some such thing, of course.